# Почему между ключом в утилите и параметром не ставится пробел?

Tags: linux, unix

Часто вижу что между ключом и его значением не ставится пробел. Почему так делают? Это какой то особый стиль?

Приведу пример: head -n1 example.com.log

Comment: Только для коротких (с одним дефисом) опций. Можете ставить, но зачем? Предположу, что даже может быть много десятилетий назад это имело и какую-то практическую цель, например, не путать с позиционными аргументами.

Comment: думаю, просто быстрее передавать получалось. Если скорость терминала была 300 бод, то пара пробелов уже могла чуточку добавить времени на передачу.

Comment: на 9600 это было б не заметно

Comment: почитайте, что в стандарте говорится по поводу option_argument: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html. в частности: «However, a conforming implementation shall also permit applications to specify the option and option-argument in the same argument string without intervening <blank> characters»

Answer (score 2):

Из-за упрощенной обработки аргументов. В функцию main() сишных программ передается массив из позиционных аргументов:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

В каждом элементе массива кусочек строки разделенный пробелом. Проходим циклом - сравнили первые 2 символа `-n` - хвост сохранили - готово.

Для простых программ, а все старые программы простые, проще написать инструкцию чтоб аргументы были слитно чем писать парсер с синтаксическим разбором.

Comment: так в старых можно было и через пробел писать. Мне кажется этот ответ притянут за уши.

Comment: Старые команды уж очень непростые, посмотрите однажды в исходный их код.